# How to create a simpledialog-like window with a combo with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, modal-dialog

simpledialog or filedialog are widgets very convenient to use.
I would like to do the same :

1. **modal window** which pops up on screen like these simpledialogs
2. **combo box** inside
3. and when I select a value in combo, **return this value** **without needing a button**

Something like:

```
def askComboValue():
  root = Tk()   #how to pops up this window?
  label = ttk.Label(root, text = "select your value")
  label.pack()
  box_value = ''
  combo = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=box_value, values=['bla', 'bli', 'blo'])
  combo.current(0)
  combo.pack()
  combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", returnValue) #how to catch this value?
  root.grab_set_global()  #is it the right way to make it modal?
  root.mainloop()
  return box_value #how to return this value?
```

Does anyone know how to deal with it?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you done any research? The internet has several examples of modal windows. For example, https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is called when there is already a tkinter window, then better use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`.  Also `box_value` should be instance of `StringVar()` instead.  `grab_set()` is used instead of `grab_set_global()` as well.

Below is an example based on your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def askComboValue(*values):
    top = tk.Toplevel() # use Toplevel() instead of Tk()
    tk.Label(top, text='Select your value').pack()
    box_value = tk.StringVar()
    combo = ttk.Combobox(top, textvariable=box_value, values=values)
    combo.pack()
    combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda _: top.destroy())
    top.grab_set()
    top.wait_window(top)  # wait for itself destroyed, so like a modal dialog
    return box_value.get()

def test():
    result = askComboValue('bla', 'bli', 'blo')
    print(result)

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text='Test', command=test).pack()
root.mainloop()
```